# Accessing ModuleId in ViewModel

Tags: javascript, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

Just curious to hear what you guys (and gals) use to access ModuleId, TabId, or TabModuleSettings while within a ViewModel?

Typically I end up doing something like

```
var localSettings = {
            "mid": "<%= ModuleId%>",
            "lid": "<%= loadId%>",
            "priceOverride": "<%= Settings[FmSettings.PartCostOverride] != null 
                ? Settings[FmSettings.PartCostOverride].ToString() 
                : String.Empty%>",
            "productOverridePrefix": "<%= Settings[FmSettings.PartNumberOverridePrefix] != null 
                ? Settings[FmSettings.PartNumberOverridePrefix].ToString() 
                : String.Empty%>",
            "productOverrideSuffix": "<%= Settings[FmSettings.PartNumberOverrideSuffix] != null 
                ? Settings[FmSettings.PartNumberOverrideSuffix].ToString() 
                : String.Empty%>"
        };
```

and then pass it to my vm like so

```
ko.applyBindings(new CalculatorViewModel(localSettings));
```

which gets out of hand fast.. I considered using ajax but that felt like overkill

What do you use to initialize your view models with a large amount of data?

Comment: You ask a very broad question I'm afraid. In general I'd say you want all that logic server side (and DRY it up a bit), make a `[Serializable]` model and use a JSON Serializer (e.g. NewtonSoft's) to render it in the view. - In any case your question would require many more details to be able to help reliably, and even then I'm not sure if SO is the place (*maybe* CodeReview.SE is a better fit?).

Comment: As a side note, as far as I understand, I'd think your question is about DotNetNuke and Javascript, but not so much about jquery or knockout.js.

Comment: Good point, thank you